# need a random number generator

Tags: c#, random, floating-point, double

I need to generate a random number between -0.5 and 0.5.

I've tried a solution on stack overflow by the user Anthony Pegram. I have modified it a bit ( i need the method to be called and used in a console.write line)

```
public static float nextfloat()
{
     Random random = new Random();
     double val = random.NextDouble();
     val -= 0.5;
     return float.MaxValue * (float)val;
}
```

by trying this I get numbers which are beyond -0.5 and 0.5 
I get things like

1.7
1.005
etc

Comment: Why are you multiplying with float.MaxValue? Don't and you're fine.

Comment: you definitely should not allocate a new random generator each time you need a random number, the sequence it will produce will have terrible statistical property and poor performance, please consider accepting Theodor's answer.

Answer (score 6):

`NextDouble` generates random numbers between 0 and 1.

```
private static Random random = new Random();
public static double GetRandomDouble_BetweenMinusHalfPlusHalf()
{
    return random.NextDouble() - 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyRandomGenerator
{
    private static readonly Random _randomGenerator = new Random();

    public static float NextFloat()
    {
        var randomValue = _randomGenerator.NextDouble() - 0.5d;

        return (float)randomValue;
    }
}
```